# How do I assign a keyboard shortcut that uses AltGr as a modifier key?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I want to assign a command to they keyboard shortcut <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, but every time I try to enter this in the Keyboard Shortcuts screen, the shortcut is set to `ISO Level3 Shift` immediately after pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Good question! I wanted to set AltGr+PrnScr it to capture screenshot of current window (since left Alt+PrnScr is broken in Maverick)

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards

Comment: @fossfreedom Would like this reopened so it stands a nonzero (albeit miniscule) chance of being answered. Closed, it signals to potential answerers “we don't care anymore”; if someone does come by with an answer, don't we want them to provide it?

Comment: @aendruk - would you like this reopened? Would you consider regularly editing with new info to whatever you've retried? - maybe a small bounty to give it more prominence?