# Xmodmap - how do I use ctrl as a modifier?

Tags: keyboard, xorg, shortcut-keys, xmodmap, remapping

Basic keyboard layout:

- <kbd>1</kbd> → `1`
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> → `!`

I would like: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+1</kbd> → `¹`. (Superscript one character). The following code allows me to type `¹`, but only with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  10 = 1 onesuperior"
```

Conclusively, I would like to keep <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for `!` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+1</kbd> for `¹`.

Comment: Apparently  not without losing Ctrl as ctrl: http://superuser.com/q/443050/334516

Comment: Are you looking to map specific keys or  Right CTRL key  as AltGr lvl3 shift where Left CTRL as standard CTRL modifier?

Comment: I do know how to map different keys, I do want to use ctrl as a modifier, but want to keep it as ctrl. However, looking at both your answers, it appears that that may be my only choice in the end.

Answer (score 2):

- This seems to me very related to:

  [How do I assign a keyboard shortcut that uses AltGr as a modifier key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45028/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-that-uses-altgr-as-a-modifier-key)

  Keep <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd> as `ISO_Level3_Shift` and try to use it as `Alt` Modifier too.

  Where in your case is reverse: Keep <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> as `Control` Modifier and an extend it to be used a Level Shift.
- I couldn't get it to work in both functions, one trial was by adding `actions`: **(Doesn't work)**

  ```
  key <RCTL> {
           type= "ONE_LEVEL",
           symbols[Group1]= [ ISO_Level5_Shift ],
           actions[Group1]= [ SetMods(modifiers=Control) ]
  };
  ```

  from [xkb - problems using virtual keys and ISO_Level3_Shift key](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2014-May/056632.html) but it just works one way only.

  Possibly, someone knowing XKB very well can make such setup.
- One setup that works for me: (no key repeat)

  1. Install and setup `xbindkeys` & `xautomation` as in [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/a/254425/44179)
  2. Add this lines to `~/.xbindkeysrc`

     ```
     "usleep 150000; xte 'keyup Control_L' 'str ¹' 'keydown Control_L'"
       m:0x4 + c:10
       control + 1
     ```

     For me, I have `¹` with <kbd>AlgGr</kbd>. So I could use this too:

     ```
     "usleep 150000; xte 'keyup Control_L' 'keydown ISO_Level3_Shift' 'key 1' 'keyup ISO_Level3_Shift' 'keydown Control_L'"
     ```
  3. Restart `xbindkeys` daemon

     ```
     pkill xbindkeys;xbindkeys
     ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xev` command and then push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, then see the keycode,  for example mine is "keycode 37" for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

However I didn't think superscript will work in editor nor terminal/console and anything except word processor. Superscript and subscript exist in word editor (LibreOffice, Ms Word, etc) but, for example, in Latex we use underscore "_" for subscript and ^ for superscript.